# Subversion merge minified JavaScript shows conflict

Tags: javascript, svn, minify

When I do a `diff $REPO1/file $REPO2/file`, `svn diff  $REPO1/file $REPO2/file`
or do the same diff operation with the minified version of the same file, I get **no** differences.

But, when I do an `svn merge $REPO2`, while in the `$REPO1` fresh checked out directory, I get an svn conflict.

Does subversion treat minified files differently when merging? Or is there a switch which I can use ONLY for minified JavaScript files which are being merged ?

```
kahmed@vm-devqa04 /extra/cr/www/developer $ diff build_8.3/htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.js build_8.2/htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.js
kahmed@vm-devqa04 /extra/co/www/developer $ diff build_8.3/htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.min.js build_8.2/htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.min.js
kahmed@vm-devqa04 /extra/co/www/developer $ 

kahmed@vm-devqa04 /extra/co/www/developer/MERGE-8.2-to-8.3/build_8.3 $ svn merge https://svn.hq.co.corp/co/perlapp/branches/build_8.2
--- Merging r262219 through r264152 into 'htdocs':
   C htdocs/css/sass/sass_compile_ca.sh
Conflict discovered in 'htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.min.js'.
Select: (p) postpone, (df) diff-full, (e) edit,
        (mc) mine-conflict, (tc) theirs-conflict,
        (s) show all options:
```

Comment: Well, did you try a `df` to see what it thinks is different? And, what are your default `diff` options? They may omit whitespace, line-endings, etc.

Comment: @Wrikken
df build_8.3/htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.min.js build_8.2/htdocs/javascript/retro_audit.min.js
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_u01
                      61927420  15919100  42862592  28% /u01
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv_u01
                      61927420  15919100  42862592  28% /u01

Comment: as far as i know, diff has no defaults

Comment: By `df`, @Wrikken meant enter `df` at the conflict prompt there.  We don't need your free disk space information.

Comment: As Charles said indeed. And for my sake: those 2 files _do_ share some ancestor?

Comment: svn --version
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
   compiled Apr 11 2013, 16:13:51

Comment: 1. Why you diff with external diff instead of `svn diff` 2. Why you diff files, but merge dirs??? 3. Why you ignore `C htdocs/css/sass/sass_compile_ca.sh` message? 4. Minified js must be considered as build-artifact and *anyway* it is badly mergeable 5. Time to update SVN was a long time ago

Comment: why check in the minified js?

Comment: 1. svn diff as the same result as diff, so i should diff directories ? 3. strange, when i merge just one file sass_compile_ca.sh it shows no conflicts 4. makes sense 5. i wish i could , but i am not the CM

Comment: i did not ignore C htdocs/css/sass/sass_compile_ca.sh message? SVN did

Comment: df:
-LENGTH_ERROR:"Description should not be more than 255 characters.",NO_QUEUE_ID:"No queue id found"},config:{MAX_SLIDER_LIMIT:500,MIN_SLIDER_LIMIT:1,ROW_PER_PAGE:10,SORT:"desc",DEFAULT_STATE:"OPEN",CLOSED_STATE:"CLOSED",AUDIT_FORM_PROCESS:"PROCESSING",POPULATED_MULTISELECTS:!
+LENGTH_ERROR:"Description should not be more than 255 characters.",NO_QUEUE_ID:"No queue id found"},config:{MAX_SLIDER_LIMIT:500,MIN_SLIDER_LIMIT:1,ROW_PER_PAGE:10,SORT:"desc",SORT_BY:"created",DEFAULT_STATE:"OPEN",CLOSED_STATE:"CLOSED",AUDIT_FORM_PROCESS:"PROCESSING",POPULATED_MULTISELECTS:!